# How do I input a local file path in ReST URL query parameter hosted on a remote machine

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I have a ReST API which takes input a file as a query parameter value and do some processing. Now when I call this API on client machine and give input a local file path, it always go and search for that file on the host machine.

I want my ReST service to search for file on the client machine instead of the host machine.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Considering that REST is more specific to the host server than the client...the only real way you could do this would be to make your REST service live on the machine you want to get data from.

Comment: Thanks Makoto for your reply. Could you please elaborate more on what u mean by making ReST service live.

Comment: Is there no way to upload the file to server first and then call this function for processing?